# Problems with repaint in gui

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, repaint

The first time a choose a image, it works just fine. But it does not work when I try to change it, the first image remains on the screen.

```
label = new JLabel("");
panel_1.add(label); 

btnAddImage = new JButton("Select Image");
btnAddImage.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
@Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
  File f = null ;
  fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
  int value = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
  if (value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
  {
    f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (f.exists())
    {
      inputImage_textField.setText(f.getName());        
      BufferedImage bi = getMyBuffImage();
      label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
      label.setBounds(0, 68, 98, 92);
      panel_1.add(label);
      panel_1.repaint();
    }
   }
 }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong when I repaint or something else is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the existing label, replace

```
label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
label.setBounds(0, 68, 98, 92);
panel_1.add(label);
panel_1.repaint();
```

with

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
label.setBounds(0, 68, 98, 92);
panel_1.revalidate();
```

Or if you want to add a second label, just replace

```
label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
label.setBounds(0, 68, 98, 92);
panel_1.add(label);
panel_1.repaint();
```

with

```
JLabel newLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
label.setBounds(0, 68, 98, 92);
panel_1.add(newLabel);
panel_1.revalidate();
```

Comment: with the edited part i am back were i started, the image shows the first time only

Comment: A mouselistener isn't called from the EDT isn't it? At least adding a new label to a visible JPanel has to be done from the EDT so that code is unsafe. Also revalidate tells the LayoutManager to recalculate the layout, this may cause children to be repainted but not necessarily the container itself. But if you just want the new Label to be correctly repainted, revalidate should do the trick - strange (although I remember some edge cases, so generally just do a repaint() after revalidate and you should be safe.. not especailly performant though)

Comment: @Voo I'm not sure if your are being ironic with your use of "isn't", but the method `mouseListener` is called from the EDT.  The EDT gets the mouse events and relay them to the listeners.  So it is safe.